# Tested negative for TB and then tested positive for TB?

Tags: tuberculosis

What could this mean, if a few years ago I had a TB test, tested negative, and then just a few weeks ago, tested positive for TB.  I know I am immunized against TB but I find it quite odd that I was tested positive when previously I had tested negative.

Comment: 1) False positive from your vaccination, 2) you were exposed to TB at some time between your first TB test and your more recent one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't specify which test was used to screen for TB, in this answer I will assume that [Mantoux test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantoux_test) was used.

---

You probably were vaccinated using [Calmette-Guérin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BCG_vaccine) vaccine.
Unfortunately this has been proven not to give an efficacious immunity against TB infection.

In this scenario there are two chances:

1. You actually were exposed to M.Tuberculosis.
2. The Mantoux test is probably a [false positive](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8668383) due to your vaccination if you are at low risk for TB infection or to other factors.

Being at low risk means an individual was not:

- In contact with another person with infectious TB
- Born or has lived in a high TB prevalence country
- Continually exposed to populations where TB prevalence is high

In both cases I would personally advise you to contact a doctor to get a chest x-ray and a [IGRA quantiferon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuantiFERON) blood test to further investigate. This is particularly advisable in your case having two different outcomes from serial testing which honestly could increase the possibility of [latent TB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_tuberculosis).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had a chest x-ray done but the doctors indicated it was more likely it was exposure to someone who had TB and not I who had TB>

Comment: You should seek consulence from a specialist who can prescribe a IGRA quantiferon test and if it confirms the diagnosis of latent tuberculosis you should begin treatment for the condition.